# Elaborar una función donde estime las medias de cada característica en un vector, sin incluir los NA´s

Tags: r, funciones, mediaqueries

tengo una base de datos con aproximadamente 10000 observaciones y 14 columnas (variables) para el ejercicio de un taller, debo crear una función que me calcule la media de todas las columnas, pero que ademas me las acomode como vector, he intentado el siguiente código, pero no me sale como vector, muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda. Mi `data.frame` fue cargado como partos.

```
mediavec <- function (x) {
  sapply (partos, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = T))}
```

En este código, me saca las medias, pero no como vectores, recibo sugerencias

Comment: Hola Luis. ¿Tienes que calcular las medias por cada variable (columna)? Siempre es conveniente incluir un ejemplo de los datos de entradas y de lo que pretendes obtener como salida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver, la media de todas las columnas, creo que la forma más simple es mediante `colMeans()`, por ejemplo:

```
set.seed(2020)
m <- matrix(runif(25), ncol=5)
colnames(m) <- c('dias', 'conteo', 'pxn', 'pxn2', 'ptotal')
m

          dias      conteo       pxn      pxn2     ptotal
[1,] 0.6469028 0.067384386 0.7644140 0.5396926 0.19679560
[2,] 0.3942258 0.129152617 0.7438358 0.9607224 0.07787092
[3,] 0.6185018 0.393117930 0.8261657 0.6535573 0.81839333
[4,] 0.4768911 0.002582699 0.4227291 0.5467153 0.94240464
[5,] 0.1360972 0.620205954 0.4092877 0.2660636 0.88422448

colMeans(m)
[1] 0.4545237 0.2424887 0.6332864 0.5933502 0.5839378
```

Y para una salida similar a lo que buscas

```
cbind(colMeans(m))

            [,1]
dias   0.4545237
conteo 0.2424887
pxn    0.6332864
pxn2   0.5933502
ptotal 0.5839378
```

Answer (score 2):

En principio, si llamas a la función `mediavec()` tal cual, obtienes las medias por columnas o variable como un vector. En realidad puedes hacer directamente `sapply(partos, mean, na.rm=T)` para obtener las medias por columnas. Hay una función que hace lo mismo es `colMeans(partos, na.rm=T)`. Por último, si tienes que escribir una función que haga lo mismo pasando un objeto (data.frame o lista) como parámetro, puedes hacer

```
mediavec2 <- function(x) unlist(sapply(x, mean, na.rm=T)) 
# la llamada sería
mediavec2(partos)
```

Marcelo hola, te agrego un ejemplo de los datos que tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y deseo, obtener una salida de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero debo crear una función, que me saque un vector como la ultima imagen, quedo atento, gracias